# Can't access virtualhost on CentOS 6 with apache 2.2.15

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have been looking around and trying different configurations on httpd.conf file of apache 2.2.15 server but I could not find a solution to my problem. So I am posting it here to get some help from a Guru.

I have this configuration on my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf on CentOS 6.7 server.

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
       ServerName example.com       (Corrected after the comment)
       DocumentRoot /var/www/dbgui       
       ErrorLog logs/dbgui-8080-error_log
       <Directory /var/www/dbgui>
              AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
       ErrorLog logs/example-80-error_log
      <Directory /var/www/laravel>
              AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I browse to http://example.com I get Laravel page (as expected) but when I browse to http://example.com:8080 I get ***"the connection has time out"***.

I have already opened the port for 8080 on the IP tables

```
output of netstat -nltup
tcp        0      0 :::8080    :::*    LISTEN      13097/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::80      :::*    LISTEN      13097/httpd
```

and

```
Output of iptables -L -nv
0   0     ACCEPT  tcp  --  *  *  0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0      tcp dpt:8080
669 41648 ACCEPT  tcp  --  *  *  0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0      tcp dpt:80
```

I don't see anything in the logs. Although it seems apache is listening on port 8080, nothing gets through and logged for port 8080.

Any suggestion to resolve this problem?

Comment: after changing iptables did you restart networking?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "I get nothing" at port 8080? What specific error do you get?

Comment: yes, i started the iptables service. I get "the connection has time out" message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help. After a lot of research and trying different things and just before throwing a chair, I finally resolved it. Here it is:
After making sure iptables has correct opened ports and protocol for tcp/8080
Next, double check the VirtualHost setup is correct and the above setup is correct. 
Next thing I did was made sure selinux is not blocking port 8080 by either disable it all together or set it to permissive mode.

```
#semanage port -l | grep http
http_cache_port_t              tcp      3128, 8080, 8118, 8123, 10001-10010
http_cache_port_t              udp      3130
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
pegasus_http_port_t            tcp      5988
pegasus_https_port_t           tcp      5989
```

As it can be seen, port 8080 is listed in http_cache_port_t and now make sure selinux does not block that

```
#setsebool -P httpd_can_network_memcache 1
```

then list it to make sure, it sets to "on" or "1"

```
# getsebool httpd_can_network_memcache
```

none of the above commands did not resolve the problem, while I was investigating the logs `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and /var/log/httpd/access_log and `/var/log/httpd/error_log` I could not find anything wrong related to port 8080
After all that, I started thinking that it does not make sense because everything configured correctly but I cannot get through. So I just took a second look at iptables output:

```
#iptables -L -nv
0     0  ACCEPT    tcp  --  *     *    0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    tcp dpt:8080
25  1316 ACCEPT    tcp  --  *     *    0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    tcp dpt:80
24  1240 ACCEPT    tcp  --  *     *    0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0    tcp dpt:443
```

Which shows 0 packet and 0 bytes came through the server. I found this site

```
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
```

It showed the port 8080 is blocked. While holding the chair in the air as the last resort :), I contacted ISP and I was told there is firewall in front of the server and port 8080 is blocked and when they opened it, I put the chair down because I finally got access.

Answer (score 0):

The port is not supposed to be part of the `ServerName` directive.

Please remove the port from the `ServerName` directive like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 ServerName example.com 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/dbgui 
 ErrorLog logs/dbgui-8080-error_log     
 <Directory /var/www/dbgui>
  AllowOverride All 
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

See the examples on apache.org [for reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I corrected it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `NameVirtualHost` param to be sure virtual hosts can be guessed from your ip/port combination

Comment: Thanks. I have tried NameVirtualHost too but it wasn't successful.